# The name "Map" does not exist in the namespace "using:Bing.Maps"

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-maps, winrt-xaml

I have added the below tag to my xaml but it didn't get recognized.I have the namespace xmlns:bing="using:Bing.Maps" added in the list of namespaces.

I have also installed bing sdk for wondows store from 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Bing Maps SDK from your project?

Answer (score -1):

That control has been deprecated. If you can use the new map control in the Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls namespace.  [How-To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)